# MySQL with Where IN and Distinct and Limit

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id, server_id, start_time, end_time 
FROM errors 
WHERE server_id in (3, 12, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30) 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 9
```

This is the query I'm trying to run to give me results where the `server_id` = `3, 12, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30`. Instead, what I receive is `server_id` = `25, 25, 12, 25, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27`. Note the repeating server_ids. The query gives me unique `id` but duplicate `server_id`.

Is there a way I can get results that would show me the last `id` for each `server_id`?

I've tried doing `ORDER BY server_id` but that gives me the same issue.

I tried running `DISTINCT` but that also does not work.

Comment: What did you try using DISTINCT with; I would think DISTINCT(server_id) and then change LIMIT 1 would achieve your request. But when you say 'last' that implies a time so your ORDER BY should be on start_time or end_time. Good luck.

Comment: The way it will work is that it won't insert a row for `server_id` unless the last entry for that server has already been closed. So retrieving the last `id` is the same as the `start_time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to use some aggregation functions.

Something like

```
select 
  server_id,
  max(id),
  avg(start_time),--for example
  avg(end_time)--for example
from errors
where server_id in (3, 12, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30) 
group by server_id
order by id desc
```

if you need tht start_time and end_time corresponding to the max id by server_id, you may do

```
select e.id, e.server_id, e.start_time, e.end_time
from errors e
join (select server_id, max(id) maxid
      from errors
      group by server_id) t
  on t.maxid = e.id and e.server_id = t.server_id
where e.server_id in (3, 12, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30) 
order by e.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you need only one record from each server with the max ID.. and relative information.  You need to limit the results to just that max ID... Here's one way...

```
SELECT id, server_id, start_time, end_time 
FROM errors 
WHERE server_id in (3, 12, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30) 
and ID = (Select max(ID) from errors E2 where E2.server_ID=errors.server_ID)
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 9
```

Comment: Works great. I assumed it would require another select but I had no idea how it would work.